# Type "First View Controller" does not conform to protocol "UITableViewDataSource"

Tags: xcode, protocols

So I can't seem to get this error away..

My code is:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var tblTasks: UITableView!

    //UITableViewDataSource
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return taskMgr.tasks.count
    }

    //UITableViewDataSource
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!{

        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "test")

        cell.textLabel!.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].desc

        return cell
    }
}
```

I used both of the required functions for `UITableViewDataSource` so I'm not sure why I keep getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the method signatures as mentioned below. Notice **!** is removed in the input params.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->  UITableViewCell {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of each method's respective `tableView` parameters should be optionals

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement two required methods: ***tableView:numberOfRowsInSection*** and ***tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath***.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayDataSource.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell

    // information here

    return cell
}
```

If you have a custom cell, change only de line:

```
var cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as MyCustomCell
```

Hope It helps!